# Matplotlib.pyplot.plot is able to plot multiple vector pairs but only when the first dimension of y matches x's

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

This was very hard to write a title for.
By introducing a bug I discovered an interesting feature of matplotlib and I would like to understand how it works:

```
import numpy as np       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal     
from scipy.spatial import distance

n = 100
X = np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
D = distance.pdist(X, 'euclidean')
D = distance.squareform(D)
S = np.exp(-D)
mvn = multivariate_normal(np.ones(100), S)
y = [mvn.rvs(1) for i in range(100)]
plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()
```

Now this seems to plot one plot `X, y[:, i]` for i in 100.

Or does it not?

Because it doesn't work with:

```
y = [mvn.rvs(1) for i in range(100)]
```

However this works again as expected:

```
y = np.array([mvn.rvs(1) for i in range(5)])
plt.plot(X, y.T)
plt.show()
```

What does matplotlib plot here?
is it `X, y[i, :]` instead?

So the correct syntax would be `Sample Space, [samples]`?

Thank you very much for your insight, I only wanted to plot one of these and made myself to this cool discovery by forgetting that rvs(1) is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)
for `plt.plot(x, y)`

> If x and/or y are 2D arrays a separate data set will be drawn for every column. If both x and y are 2D, they must have the same shape. If only one of them is 2D with shape (N, m) the other must have length N and will be used for every data set m.

Its basically a convenient behaviour instead looping manually over your data.

Comment: thanks! I was reading that, but I didn't quite understand it.
So looping over makes sense, it would be like `for y in ys: plot(X, y)`?